# SUN X4250 OS SuSe - ILOM IP?

Tags: linux, sun, sles

is there a way or command if im login to SuSe Linux shell which can show me the ILOM IP address. Machine type SUN Netra X4250.

Comment: I miss ALOM :( ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the serial port connected up on the server you can run the following command which will tell you what the IP is

```
cd /SP/network    
cat pendingipaddress
```

by default this is setup to use DHCP If you need to use a static IP try following [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19203-01/819-1160-13/sp_initial_setup.html#23355).

Answer (score 1):

You can't find it out, but I think it defaults to coming up via DHCP, so your DHCP server might be able to tell you.  Alternately, you can go into the BIOS and set it there.

Update: It looks like [ipmitool](http://ipmitool.sourceforge.net/) might also be able to interface with ILOM.

Comment: Sun doesn't have Linux ILOM interfaces? (I don't know, I'm familiar with HP equipment where there are tools).